# how can i do to make position:fixed work well

Tags: css, css-position

i have a div,

it's width is 200px ,height is 150px,

i want the style of div's position is fixed

To make it centered horizontally and vertically centered

Comment: Too bad it's not a bukket. I hear there's a walrus looking for one.

Comment: You google it! http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/exactly-center-an-imagediv-horizontally-and-vertically/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
div{
    position:fixed;
    margin:auto;
    left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
    width:200px; height:150px;
}
```